# JWPLAYER 5 - JavaScript API onError

Tags: javascript, jwplayer

Hello can someone help me to change the text when the file cannot load and error appear I want to change the error and write something from my own...I don't know how to do it ;/..

Comment: Provide a link to where you are running the player and we can show you where to add it.

Comment: http://myseacheck.besaba.com/

Comment: Come on help me please

Comment: Take a deep breath and relax, it's the weekend. You can't expect support 24x7.

Answer (score 1):

You would change this code:

```
events: {
onComplete: function() { alert("OnlyHDMovies.tk - Thanks for Watching"); }
},
```

To this:

```
events: {
onComplete: function() { alert("OnlyHDMovies.tk - Thanks for Watching"); },
onError: function() { jwplayer().load('new_file.mp4');jwplayer().play(); }
},
```

That will load a new file, or you can really do anything inside of the function that you want, whenever there is an error. This is only an example.

Comment: Its working but first its display the error and if I play it again its playing the file

Comment: I want to change the text when error comes..Like video not found or access denied...and if its possible to make player play from xml or rss file...that include access only for some domains

Comment: It is not possible to change the text. To make it automatically play it, just do this - onError: function() { jwplayer().load('new_file.mp4');jwplayer().play(); } , I will update my answer.

Comment: I cant change the error that appears..only change the video that playS?

Comment: That error cannot be changed. You can always just have the page re direct, or have the page simply refresh. Basically anything in JS is possible to do here.

Comment: How can I play video like this one http://bit.ly/1rmjlXX on jw player 5 last version its not playable ;/

Comment: We don't support Google Videos. Only YouTube.

Comment: Play from picasa to jwplayer 5 last version could be? :P

Comment: No, we don't support it.